# Getting specific column from sql database using raw query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this raw query that extracts data from the database table in Laravel

```
 $username = DB::table('hotspot_users')
 ->select('userName')  
 ->where('assignedTo', '786')->get();
```

I get these values: `[{"userName":"kim"}]`

but I want to extract just the username "kim" itself, not an array. I have tried to do this without success:

```
 $convert1=json_decode($username);
 $newusername=$convert1->userName;
```

but i get an error: Trying to get property 'userName' of non-object

Any idea how I can solve this

Comment: Can you post the result of the query?

Comment: I had indicated; It comes in this form  [{"userName":"kim"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the result of `DB` as php *stdClass* object, so you can iterate over it and get every variable that is queried. Something like below code may help you.

**In case of using `get()`**

```
$data = DB::table('hotspot_users')
           ->where('assignedTo', '786')->select('userName')->get();

foreach ($data as $datum) {
    $result[] = $datum->userName;
}
```

**In case of using `first()`**

```
$data = DB::table('hotspot_users')
            ->where('assignedTo', '786')->select('userName')->first()->userName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what you're doing, you can just do this:

```php
HotspotUser::where('assignedTo', 786)->pluck('userName');
```

Now you will have a collection of names; or if you only want the first one:

```php
HotspotUser::where('assignedTo', 786)->first()->user_name;
```

(I'm not certain if the property will be `user_name` or `userName`; you should have simple column names to make things easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
 As you mentioned that is an array `[{"userName":"kim"}]` 
So you have two choices

#### First , you `first` insted of `get`

```php
 $username = DB::table('hotspot_users')
 ->select('userName')  
 ->where('assignedTo', '786')->first();

 $newusername=$convert1->userName;
```

#### Second , get the first element of array

```php
 $username = DB::table('hotspot_users')
 ->select('userName')  
 ->where('assignedTo', '786')->get();

 $username = reset($username);
 $convert1=json_decode($username);
 $newusername=$convert1['userName'];
```

Comment: Thanks With the first method I got an error Json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: with the second i get the error Trying to get property 'userName' of non-object I don't know what am doing wrong

Comment: I update both of them , can you try them again and say the result?